# Facebook PHP SDK Verify Like returns "NOT A FAN" for some Fans

Tags: php, facebook, sdk, facebook-page

We are struggling with a problem that is driving me insane.

Using this code...

```
$facebook = new Facebook($config);

$uid = $facebook->getUser();

if ($uid) {
  try {
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $uid = null;
  }
}

if(!$uid) {
$params = array(
  'scope' => 'email',
  'redirect_uri' => 'https://www.mysite.com/'
);

$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);

header("Location: $loginUrl");
}

$email = $facebook->api('/me?fields=email');
$email = $email['email'];

$verifyLike = $facebook->api('/me/likes/page_id');
if($verifyLike['data']) {
    echo "FAN"; 
} else {
    echo "NOT A FAN";
}
```

We are getting about 8% of users who are seeing "NOT A FAN" and they are in fact a Fan of our page.

I can't for the life of me figure out the problem, and I am running out of ideas.

Anyone have any idea what is causing this issue, and more importantly what we can do to fix it?

Thank you.

UPDATE 2/25/12
Reported the bug to Facebook, and they changed the bug status to "Triaged" and the priority to "Low", but they don't yet have a solution and are still looking into it. No one else is experiencing this issue?

Comment: Is it possible they are explicitly removing the permissions your app would need to see this when they authorize your app?  Just a guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a bug of facebook, if the user’s pages are set to less than everyone privacy, you must ask the user for the user_likes extended permission.

So these 8% of your users have more privacy on their facebook profiles and their likes are not public. For all other users you don't even need a valid access_token in the api request.